# What is minimum Servlet API version with which log4j2 will work?

Tags: servlets, log4j2

[Log4j2 documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/webapp.html) describes configuration on Servlet API "3.0 and higher" and 2.5, but mentions nothing about earlier versions.  It does not say they are supported or not supported.  Does anyone know the minimum Servlet API version that will work with log4j2?

Answer (score 1):

Log4j2 has not been tested on anything less than 2.5. That said, nothing comes to mind as to why 2.4 wouldn't work. But it is not formally supported.

Comment: Thanks.  IMHO, the log4j2 website should not be silent on this issue.  An explicit authoritative statement on this should be made there.